# Rogue Widgets from Sitefinity

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

I'm having a very hard time trying to track this issue down.  I have an outdated database.

```
The controller with the name 'Controller' cannot be resolved.
```

I am not sure why I get this issue and how I can remove it from my template.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: where do you see this error, on a page? if you open the page in the backend editor do you see the widget there or does that page crash as well? what if you open the page template that defines the page, can you access the widget and remove it there?

Comment: I pulled this site from TFS and my data was outdated.  Is there a way to keep this from happening?  If someone deletes an existing widget because it is no longer used, why doesn't it inform you rather than give a vague error?

Comment: it depends; if the widget is on the page but the files for the widget are deleted, then you will get an exception because the page is expecting the widget to be there. on the page backend, it should indeed notify you and give you the opportunity to delete the widget. if you load the frontend page but the widget doesn't exist, unfortunately Sitefinity just crashes. just the way it is for now...